# How do I predict on multiple samples on an LSTM model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, predict

In Keras, if I want to predict on my LSTM model for multiple instances, that are based on independent and new data from the training data, does the input array need to include the amount of time steps used in training? And, if so, can I expect that the shape of the input array for model.predict to be the same as the training data? (Ie [number of samples to be predicted on, their timesteps, their features])?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between the 'sample' or 'batch' axis and the time steps and features dimensions.

The number of samples is variable - you can train (fit) your model on thousands of samples, and make a prediction for a single sample.

The times steps and feature dimensions have to be identical for `fit` and `predict` - that is because the weights etc. have the same dimensions for the input layer.

In that, an LSTM is not that much different from a DNN.

There are cases (eg. one-to-many models) in which the application is different, but the formal design (i.e. input shape, output shape) is the same.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is clear and precise, and best of all, quick, and for that I’m appreciative, so thank you again. To summarize your answer: as long as the features that were used in training are also present in the n number of samples to be predicted on, and as long as the same number of time steps are present in the n number of samples to be predicted on, then the array is of correct shape for predicting on multiple samples.

Comment: If you have a look at the `summary()` of the models, you see the batch/sample dimension is always shown as None, e.g. (None, 128,3) - 128,3 being the feature dimension (including time steps)